# How best to encrypt/decrypt very large files in .Net Core

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, encryption

My .Net Core 2 application generates very large files (80 MB+), using a third party library method. This method writes to a Stream. The end user can download the generated files via an MVC web page, which returns the file as a stream to the browser, using a `FileStreamResult`.

Normally, I would use a `FileStream` to write the file to disk. And another `FileStream` in my MVC action method to read the file.

However, the files now have to be encrypted while stored on disk on the server (they contain very sensitive information).

Because the files are very large, I want to use a Stream based approach to encrypting/decryping them, rather than loading them into memory.

I would like to use the new .Net Core data protection system, using `IDataProtectionProvider` and `IDataProtector`, because it is very easy to use, manages keys for me, etc. However, its `IDataProtector.Protect` and `Unprotect` methods simply encrypt/decrypt byte arrays. So they are not stream based.

The older `CryptoStream` class does support Streams, so I could use that. But I would have to do my own key management. And because other parts of my application already use the .Net Core data protection system, I would wind up with two ways of doing encryption/decryption.

How can I encrypt/decrypt 80MB+ files using the new .Net Core data protection system?

Alternatively, is there a way to use the .Net Core data protection system with `CryptoStreamd`?

Or is there some other option that I missed?

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Like custom implementation of streams for the .net Core DPAPI?

Comment: Why storing the decrypted file in RAM is considered a bad thing? (Skipping my assumptions regarding the backdoors or ways to read the virtual memory segment from another process) It is kind of computationally inefficient to decrypt file each time, despite the fact that modern standards (e.g. AES) are high-perfomant.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Yes, something like that. Or maybe a Nuget library. Or maybe there is a simple way to accomplish this. I'm pretty sure I'm not the first person who wants to use .Net Core DPAPI with Streams.

Comment: @ArtemIgnatovich I think storing the decrypted file in RAM is a bad thing because it can be very big.

Comment: My question out of this is, why isn't there an overload method and why didn't they implement it? My tingles tell me it isn't possible, I don't think the DPAPI lends itself to that. Think about it, you typically salt/hash a zillion times so how can you randomise via a incomplete stream? Something magic in the Crypto Library you reference actually makes me think that's reversible.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, Microsoft documentation on these classes is literally as unhelpful as it could possibly be, but I'd say it is a fair assumption that these classes use an AEAD cipher mode underneath.  This makes them inappropriate for use with files of the size you are dealing with and also explains why no streaming interface is available.

I suggest using `CryptoStream` as you outline in your answer, but consider the difficulties you will encounter around integrity - you'll need to pass through the stream once to produce and confirm the MAC and then pass through again to actually decrypt - otherwise you'll end up streaming decrypted data to the consumer before verifying if the MAC is actually correct.

Comment: A reference or two to elaborate would be great